# Next JS project is breaking after manually adding a folder to the root directory?

Tags: next.js

Trying to learn/build a Next JS project.   I narrowed down an issue that was breaking the project and stopping the dev server from loading.

After manually adding a 'util' folder to the root directory, to add mongodb code, the project would no longer load with 'npm run dev'

Does anyone know why?

- I changed the folder name, and it still doesnt work.
- I deleted the added folder and it still doesnt work.
- Im using typescript

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack over flow! . Try to provide us with more information such as the folder structure of your project.Also any code inside the util folder if possible.This would allow us to help you better.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `.next` folder?

Comment: Aye that fixed my problem.  The project will run after deleting the folder.  Still not sure why adding new folders breaks the project though?    Do you usually have to delete .next everytime you add a folder?

Comment: Not every time. But this is quite common in Next.js. Sometimes performing certain actions like modifying the project's folder structure can lead to issues with Next's cache and that's when you should delete this folder.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I was stuck for hours on this.